# How to resolve CyclicDefinitionError in factory_boy SubFactory call?

Tags: django, factory-boy

I have following models

```
# in ModelA_App/models.py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    TYPEA = 1
    TYPEB = 2
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
       (TYPEA, 'TypeA'),
       (TYPEB, 'TypeB')
    )
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    name - models.CharField(max_length = 100)

#in ModelB_App/models.py
from ModelA_App.models import ModelA

class ModelB(models.Model):
    label = models.TextFiled()
    model_a = models.OneToOneField(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And I have following factories:

```
#in ModelA_App/factories.py
class ModelAFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
       model = ModelA

    name = factory.Faker('word')
    type = ModelA.TYPEA

#in ModelB_App/factories.py
from ModelA_App.models import ModelA
from ModelA_App.factories import ModelAFactory

class ModelBFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
       model = ModelB

    label = factory.Faker('text')
    model_a = SubFactory(ModelAFactory, type = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: '%d' % o.type))

    class Params:
       type = ModelA.TYPEA
```

I'd like to be able to create `ModelB` object with `ModelA` having `TYPEB`.
Trying line `ModelBFactory.create(type = ModelA.TYPEB)`
results in error:

> factory.errors.CyclicDefinitionError: Cyclic lazy attribute definition
> for 'type'; cycle found in ['type']

Additionally, when I change `type` name in `Params` class to e.g. `model_type` having:

```
model_a = SubFactory(ModelAFactory, type = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: '%d' % o.model_type))
```

It fails with

> AttributeError: The parameter 'model_type' is unknown.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write a `SubFactory`, the additional definitions you provide are anchored to that sub-factory. What you have written is equivalent to:

```py
class SubModelAFactory(ModelAFactory):
    class Meta:
        # Not required - implied by class inheritance
        model = models.ModelA

    type = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: '%d' % o.type)

class ModelBFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    ...
    model_a = factory.SubFactory(SubModelFactory)
```

Instead, you should go "up" a level, as described in [the `SelfAttribute` docs](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#parents):

```py
class ModelBFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    ...
    model_a = factory.SubFactory(
        SubModelFactory,
        type=factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: '%d' % o.factory_parent.type),

        # If the value can be passed without conversion, use:
        type=factory.SelfAttribute('..type'),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution. `ModelBFactory` should look like this:

```
#in ModelB_App/factories.py
from ModelA_App.models import ModelA
from ModelA_App.factories import ModelAFactory

class ModelBFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
       model = ModelB

    label = factory.Faker('text')
    model_a = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: ModelAFactory(type = o.type))

    class Params:
       type = ModelA.TYPEA
```

Instead of putting `ModelAFactory` attribute as a `LazyAttribute` I had to put whoel factory as one.

Comment: this solution kinda works, but you'll lose all benefits from `SubFactory`: sharing a strategy (`ModelBFactory.build` / `ModelBFactory.create`), the ability to override fields at call time (`ModelBFactory(model_a__name='example')`), etc.